# Move a single box around a page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a flash uploader that can only be initialized once. And I have multiple fields across a large form that need to use the uploader.

I would like to:

1. Initialize the uploader (load the file just once, not load multiple uploaders or lines of code)
2. Move an element, say a DIV around a page

What JQuery method would allow me to move a div around a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$("element").animate(({'top':'20px';'left':'20px'},2000);`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: you have an extra "(" after animate.